# random excluding 0 in python

Tags: python, random, while-loop

I want to pick up a number between -1.5 and 1.5 but this shouldn't be 0.

I am using:

```
x = random.uniform( -1.5, 1.5 )
```

but I have to write a condition to exclude 0 like:

```
x = 0
while (x==0):
    x = random.uniform( -1.5, 1.5 )
```

Is it another possibility to write this without a condition?

Comment: what's wrong with this approach, it has to be fastest one

Comment: If you replace the `x = 0` with `x = random.uniform( -1.5, 1.5 )` your acceptance/rejection approach will be much more efficient than the proposals to generate on the half-range and use a second random number to flip the sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
1.5 * (1.0 - random.random())
```

and then do a random decision for whether to negate the result.  Since `random.random() < 1.0`, you should (numerically) not get a zero.

**EDIT**:

It has been pointed out (correctly) that this needs two random decisions.  To do so with one random decision, use the following:

```
v = 3.0 * random.random()
result = 1.5 - v
if v >= 1.5:
    result = v - 3.0
```

If `0.0 <= v < 1.5`, you get `1.5 - v`, and `0.0 <= range < 1.5`.

Otherwise, `1.5 <= v < 3.0`, and you get `v - 3.0`, so `0.0 > range >= -1.5`.

Comment: +1 because it is way to do it without a condition, as the question asked. Nevertheless I would probably go with the example from the question

Comment: This isn't without a condition, the condition is in the "random decision for whether to negate the result."  This solution requires two calls to random() for every value generated plus the conditional for whether to negate or not, and is going to be less efficient than checking for zero and having to generate a second value roughly once every 2**31 values.

Comment: Absolutely-- in general this is not more efficient than the original solution.  But there's a way to use only one random call, which I've listed above.

Answer (score 2):

what you are doing is fine (there's no api method for this), but i suspect that you should have something more like:

```
epsilon = 1e-10  # for example
while abs(x) < epsilon: x = random.uniform(-1.5, 1.5)
```

because the most likely reason to avoid zero is for numerical reasons, and typically very small values that are non-zero will also cause problems.

one other thing you could do is take advantage of the half-open nature of random():

```
x = 1.5 * (1 - random.random())
if random.randint(0, 1): x = -x
```

but i think the code you have is clearer (and while the above seems technically correct i am not sure i trust it in all cases, with rounding etc).

[edit: i came up with the half-open idea independently of creichen, but got it backwards, so fixed after seeing their code]